# Problem when importing tikzfigure containing step function from Python using matplotlib2tikz

Tags: pgfplots, matplotlib2tikz

I generate a step function in Python and export it as a `tikzfigure`, saved in the file `step.tex`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib2tikz import save as tikz_save

plt.step(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]), np.array([10, 5, 15, 20]))
tikz_save('step.tex')
```

The content of the `step.tex` file is

```
% This file was created by matplotlib2tikz v0.6.6.
\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0.12156862745098,0.466666666666667,0.705882352941177}

\begin{axis}[
xmin=0.85, xmax=4.15,
ymin=4.25, ymax=20.75,
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
x grid style={lightgray!92.026143790849673!black},
y grid style={lightgray!92.026143790849673!black}
]
\addplot [semithick, color0]
table {%
1 10
2 5
3 15
4 20
};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

After importing this file in LaTex, using the code

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
Hello\\
\input{step.tex}
\end{document}
```

I noticed that the step function is replaced by non-horizontal lines connecting the dots ('first-order hold' instead of 'zero-order hold', as if I had used `plt.plot()` instead of `plt.step()`):

[image]

Is this a problem on the Python side (that I should ask elsewhere), or on the LaTeX side?

Comment: Well, it's sort of both. The plot is wrong because the `const plot` key is missing, but `const plot` is missing because `matplotlib2tikz` has failed to properly "translate" the `step` plot to `pgfplots` code. Hence, I would report the problem at https://github.com/nschloe/matplotlib2tikz/issues

Comment: Or rather, it's `const plot mark right` you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The key is `\addplot [const plot]`.

---

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0.12156862745098,0.466666666666667,0.705882352941177}

\begin{axis}[
xmin=0.85, xmax=4.15,
ymin=4.25, ymax=20.75,
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
x grid style={lightgray!92.026143790849673!black},
y grid style={lightgray!92.026143790849673!black}
]
\addplot [semithick, color0,const plot]
table {%
1 10
2 5
3 15
4 20
};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See `pgfplots` documentation (Revision 1.15) in section **4.5.3 Constant Plots**.

[image]

Comment: OK, I did not know this. You would expect that the `matplotlib2tikz` library would add this automatically.

Comment: @Karlo Apparently, that's not the case :).