# How can I set the comma as decimal separator in all tikzfigures in my document?

Tags: tikz-pgf, icomma

I am using a lot of (externally generated) `tikzfigure`s in a document. They have a structure such as the example shown in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/386202/problem-when-importing-tikzfigure-containing-step-function-from-python-using-mat).

I read in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31276/number-format-in-pgfplots-axis) how to set the comma as decimal separator inside a single `tikzfigure`. How can I automatically set the comma as decimal separator in all the `tikzfigure`s contained in my document?

Note that I am also using the `icomma` package to use the comma as decimal separator in LaTeX code.

Comment: Have you checked out the setup macros `\pgfplotsset` and `\tikzset` respectively?

Comment: Could you please add [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: @Bobyandbob The MWE is in the linked question (first link).

Comment: @Karlo I prefer to see a MWE in the question (not in a link "structure such as the example"). Does `\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,use comma}` help? Or is it related to [Global definition of pgfplots axes style conflicts with colorbar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247423/124842)?